# Database direct import from Excel?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, import

I've worked on SQL Server 2014 and I need to import data in it from Excel.
'Till now, I've imported data by right-clicking on the `current database -> Tasks -> Import Data`.

I want to know if there is a SQL syntax to import data directly into a table?

Comment: Take care to google it first. There are thousands of samples/tutorials and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try OPENROWSET

```
Insert into SQLServerTable 
Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
    'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

Comment: It gives me the error: Msg 7302, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".